# R- ggplot bad sorted graphics

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am making a grapchic with ggplot. The code is the next:

```
ggplot(aes(x=hour,y=result), data=subset2)+geom_bar(position="dodge", stat="identity")
```

the problem are:

-In the hour axis appears before the hour `´10:00´` than `´9:00´`

-In the result axis appears  `20` before `3`

I guess the problem is that reads the first digit, but I don't really know how to fix this.

[image]

Cheers

Comment: What is `subset2`?

Comment: It sounds like your dataset is storing your variables as strings.

Comment: It is a dataset

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
subset2 <- data.frame(hour= c("7:00","7:30","8:00","8:30","9:00","9:30","10:00","10:30","11:00","11:30"),
                  result= c("0","44,17","75,71","37,86","41,01","37,86","37,86","37,86","37,86","31,55"))
library(chron)
subset2$hour <- as.character(times(paste(subset2$hour,"00",sep=":")))
subset2$result <- as.numeric(gsub(",","",subset2$result))

ggplot(aes(x=hour,y=result), data=subset2) +
  geom_bar(position="dodge", stat="identity") +
  theme(axis.text.x=element_text(angle=90,hjust=1,vjust=0.5))
```

I updated my code after seeing your sample data. 
Please don't forget to mark as answer if this solution helps you :)

Comment: Thanks for the response Prem,

check my edit. I have tried your code, and with that I can't fix my problem.

the as.numeric is changing my values, and the hour just has added :00 at the end, but I am the same situation.

Comment: Please mark as 'answer' if it solved your problem :)